# Dynamic array of structs in C using realloc

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a simple dynamic array of structures, but I'm unsure about how to go about doing it.

I have

```
n = 1;
typedef struct {
   char wordName [50];
   int counter;
}Words;

Words * array;
```

And now I want to reallocate it in this loop.

```
if(strlen(token) > 6){
        array = (Words*)realloc(array, sizeof(Words)*n++);
        strcpy(array->wordName, token);
        //printf("%s ", array->wordName);
        array++;
    }
```

I can add data to the structure, it prints it all out in a loop just fine. But when I add array++, I get:

```
realloc(): invalid pointer
```

Am I accessing the data incorrectly? Or do I not even have any more pointers beyond the head?

Comment: Try `++n` which will give you the incremented value of `n`.

Comment: This is _all_ the important code?  Is the `realloc` the only place where you allocate memory?  Your variable `array` is uninitialized, which might explain the "invalid pointer" message.  You must initialize it to `NULL`.

Comment: `array` is a special pointer returned by realloc. If you want realloc again, you need pass old `array` value without change. Something like `b = realloc(a, size1); c = realloc(b, size2);`.  You can not do `b = realloc(a, size1); b++; c=realloc(b, size2);`. Maybe you can make a backup first, like `b=realloc(a, size1); b_tmp=b++; c=realloc(b_tmp, size2);`.

Answer (score 4):

`array++;` causes array to advance by `sizeof (a_pointer)` so it now no longer points to address first returned by `realloc()`. That means any future attempt to `realloc()` with the new address of array will result in the error *"Invalid pointer, pointer was not initially allocated with call to malloc, calloc or realloc"*.

Further, if `array` is not initialized `NULL`, then you cannot use `realloc()` for the initial allocation. Initializing `n  = 1;` mixes a *count* with and *index*. Always keep the count so it is the next *index* to be filled. For `0` you can use an `if / else` or `ternary`, e.g.

```c
  n = 0;
  ...
  if (n) { /* if n > 0 (not 1st allocation, use realloc) */
    /* always realloc using a temporary pointer */
    void *tmp = realloc (array, (n + 1) * sizeof *array); 
    if (!tmp) {   /* validate EVERY allocation */
      /* handle error, return */
    }
    array = tmp;  /* assign reallocated block to array */
    n += 1;       /* increment count */
  }
  else {  /* initial allocation */
    array = malloc (sizeof *array);
    if (!array) { /* validate EVERY allocation */
      /* handle error, return */
    }
    n += 1;       /* increment count */
  }
  /* rest of your strcpy here
   * VALIDATE strlen(token) > 0 AND < 50
   */
  /* note: you can consolidate both n += 1; here. duplicated for clarity */
```

You always call `realloc()` with a temporary pointer because when (not if) `realloc()` fails it returns `NULL` which will overwrite the address pointing to the allocated block of memory creating a memory leak. e.g. never do:

```c
  pointer = realloc (pointer, size);
```

Instead, by using a temporary pointer, if `realloc()` fails, `pointer` (your `array`) will still point to the last allocated and still valid block of memory allowing you to use what is stored there AND allowing you to `free()` that block of memory when you are done with it.

Note, you can use a ternary, but it is much less readable:

```c
  Words *array = NULL;
  size_t n = 0;
  ...
  void *tmp = realloc (array, sizeof *array * n ? n + 1 : 1);
    if (!tmp) {  /* validate EVERY allocation */
      /* handle error, return */
    }
    array = tmp;
    n += 1;
    /* rest of your strcpy here
     * VALIDATE strlen(token) > 0 AND < 50
     */
```

In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`), it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: `always realloc using a temporary pointer` was looking for this +1!

Comment: I guess I should expand on that in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Why even consider a `?:`?  Instead of `sizeof *array * n ? n + 1 : 1`, why not `sizeof *array * (n + 1)`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - always one step ahead, quite true. `n + 1` will do without the ternary at all. I suspect the stuck code-pattern in my thought process involved a postscript `n++`. But not needed with the explicit addition. (thwack... light-bulb winks on `:)`